# How to change label length on AS3 checkbox?

Tags: actionscript-3, checkbox

I have a checkbox label that needs to be about 50 characters long, but it's being truncated at 13 characters.

How do I code it to allow longer text in the label please?

Thank you

Comment: Try increasing the **width** of the said component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow two different ways:

- The first: Try in your checkBox (s: or mx:) to increase the `width` property

  ```
  <s:CheckBox id="myChk" width="100" />
  <mx:CheckBox id="myChk" width="100" />
  ```
- The second: You can wrap your checkbox in a `FormItem` (s: or mx:) so, you can manage the width of `FormItem` and your checkbox manage only the tick select.

  ```
  <s:FormItem id="myItem" label="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA">
      <s:CheckBox id="myChk" />
  </s:FormItem>
  ```